# Warning: embedded null when reading .xlsx file

Tags: r, null, warnings

I am having trouble with a warning message that i continue to receive when reading an excel file using the read.table function. it says that line 1 contains an embedded null.
[warning message in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoUZQ.png)

My excel file has headers but they start on row 3 which is why i believe i am getting this warning and i am not sure how to fix it. below is a screen capture of the excel file.
[excel data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poOJl.png)

the goal is to Load the FaceBook dataset into data frames and create a data frame for each file type. i have the same data file in a .txt , .csv and the .txt.

Comment: Try with e.g. `readxl::read_xlsx`. You can't read an excel file with `read.table`. It's for reading text files which are in a table format, like e.g. `.csv` or `.tsv` or ... files.

Comment: library(readxl)
read_excel(Facebook Friends.xlsx, skip = 2)